# Obtener value de un input type="file"

Tags: php, ajax, input

Estuve leyendo que hay un truco para obtenerlo, sin embargo no lo he logrado.
Estoy haciendo un botón editar y quiero que si no ha seleccionado ningún archivo que se guarde el anterior.

```
<input type="file" class="form-control input-xxlarge  Table clear input" id="file" name="file" style="border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px">
<span name="old" id="old" value="<?php $Logo; ?>"></span>
```

Me muestra bien el valor pero a la hora que trato de obtener el valor esta NULL.

```
if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $url        = '/web/assets/images/clinicas/';
    $ext        = Yii::$app->utils->takeFileExtension($_FILES['file']['name']);
    $filename   = "{$_FILES['file']['name']}";
    $final_path = "{$url}" . $filename;
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $final_path)) {
        $output['done']    = true;
        $output['content'] = "<div class='alert alert-error'>La imagen ha sido cargada.</div>";
        $modelo->Logo      = $filename;
    } else {
        $output['content'] = "<div class='alert alert-error'>No fue posible guardar la imagen.</div>";
    }
} else {
    $oldfile = $_POST['old'];
    $modelo->Logo = $oldfile;
}
```

Lo que quiero hacer es que si no se selecciona ningún archivo guarde siempre el anterior pero, ¿Cómo puedo obtener el valor anterior de la base de datos?

Comment: Saludos. Los datos que tienes en tu script (en tu caso php) será de lo que recibe; por tanto deberás validar y realizar los procesos necesarios cuando se reciba y cuando no el archivo. Te sugiero (por asi decirlo/expresarlo) 2 SQL una que incluya se recibio el archivo y otra no para ejecutarla según corresponda.

Comment: En `$_FILES['file']` se incluye el atributo `error` y solo necesitas analizar para saber qué hacer, por ejemplo: `$_FILES['file']['error'] == 0` quiere decir que se seleccionó un archivo y fue subido a carpeta temporal, a partir de ahí puedes comenzar a procesarlo. `$_FILES['file']['error'] == 4` el usuario no seleccionó un archivo para subir. Más [códigos de error](https://www.php.net/manual/es/features.file-upload.errors.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te comparto un código que use para guardar el anterior solo adaptalo

Este es el backend de php
Lo que hago es guardar en una variable la imagen guardada

```
$Img_guardada = $_POST["Img_guardada"];
    $Img = $_FILES["Img"]["tmp_name"];

    $errores = '';

    if (empty($Item) or empty($Nombre_Producto) or empty($Descripcion) or empty($Especificaciones) or empty($Moneda) or empty($Precio)) {
        $errores .= '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible">
                         <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                         <h4><i class="icon fa fa-ban"></i> Alerta!</h4>
                                  Por favor llena todos los campos.
                         </div>';
    } else {
    
    if (empty($Img["name"]) //Aqui le digo que si no hay archivo use el guardado
    ){
        $Img = $Img_guardada;

    } else { //Aqui le digo que si sube una nueva imagen la reemplace

    $ruta = "imagenes_subidas/";
    
    $archivo_subido = "img/" . $ruta . $_FILES["Img"]["name"];

    $img_cinta = "img/imagenes_subidas/" . $_FILES["Img"]["name"];

    move_uploaded_file($Img, $archivo_subido);

    }
```

Y este es el formulario

```
<?php

$statement = $conexion->prepare('SELECT Img FROM Imagenes WHERE ProductoID = :ID');

  $statement->execute(array(':ID'=>$ID));

  $resultado = $statement->fetch();

  $formulario_img = $resultado;

?>

<div class="form-group">
                  <label for="InputFile">Imagenes</label>
                    <input type="file" name="Img" class="form-control" id="InputFile" placeholder="Elegir Imagen">
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="hidden" name="Img_guardada" class="form-control" id="InputFile2" value="<?php echo $post["Img"]; ?>">
                  </div>
```